# Get User Interactions in iOS Cocoa Touch Framework

Tags: ios, dynamic-library, cocoa-touch

I am trying to develop an Cocoa Touch Framework or a dynamic Library.

This Framework should intercept the touch, swipe, pan gestures on views. For starting let us assume that I want to intercept touch event on every control (UIButton, UIView etc. ) and it should be captured in the Framework where I would use that data for further processing.

Could anyone direct me in correct direction about how to target this?

Comment: Look at a method swizzling: http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/ . I think it is something that you need. (I think you can swizzle beginTouch method in UIView class to achieve a needed behaviour).

Comment: @AndrewRomanov I am developing the library using Swift and using the method swizzling. But in the application, I need to call the super's implementation to get the Method Swizzling started. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: What about swizzle methods inside any your classes (if you do not want to call super)? For example you can create method: subscribeToTouchesForClass(Class classVar), and set your class as classVar.

Comment: @AndrewRomanov could you please help me with a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace methods in UI classes you can replace methods in base classes (UIView or UIViewController). If you do not want to call `super` inside a code of your classes. You should swizzle methods inside any of your subclass.
To achieve this,  I see two solutions:
 1. First, create custom subclass for UIView, UIControl, UIViewController. These subclasses should have swizzled methods and don't call `super`.

```
@interface CustomViewBase
@end
@implementation CustomViewBase
 + (void)initialize
 {
  [SwizleLib swizleMethodsInClass:[self class]];
 }

- (BOOL)touchBegin<.....>
{
   return YES;
}
@end
```

And you will create subclasses of CustomViewBase and call `super` implementation for any methods. (Don't forget that you should create subclasses for UIView, UIControl, UIViewController, UIButton, UITableViewCell).
2.If you do not want to change a base class (you want to use UIView as subclass for your UI classes), you should swizzle methods in your subclasses (since, you do not want to call `super`).